# Add Calculated column to Dataframe Based on other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a calculated column in a dataframe based on a condition that includes other dataframe.

Example:

I have a dataframe Users that contains:

```
Out[4]:
                                        UserID  Active  BaseSalaryCOP  BaseSalaryUSD    FromDate      ToDate
0  557058:36103848-2606-4d87-9af8-b0498f1c6713    True        9405749        2475.20  05/11/2020  05/11/2021
1  557058:36103848-2606-4d87-9af8-b0498f1c6713    True        3831329        1008.24  05/11/2020  04/11/2021
2  557058:7df66ef4-b04d-4ce9-9cdc-55751909a61e    True        3775657         993.59  05/11/2020  05/11/2021
3  557058:b0a4e46c-9bfe-439e-ae6e-500e3c2a87e2    True        9542508        2511.19  05/11/2020  05/11/2021
4  557058:b25dbdb2-aa23-4706-9e50-90b2f66b60a5    True        8994035        2366.85  05/11/2020  05/11/2021
```

And I have another called Rate that contains the UserId.
I want to add A calculate column to add the BaseSalaryUSD Divide between 18 where the USer ID match and ToDate match as well.

Something like (If date Match with toDate and USerID Match then add a new colum that contains User["BaseSalaryUSD"] / 18):

```
Out[5]:
                                     AccountID           Date      rate
0  557058:36103848-2606-4d87-9af8-b0498f1c6713     04/21/2021    137.51
2  557058:7df66ef4-b04d-4ce9-9cdc-55751909a61e     05/11/2021     55.19
3  557058:b0a4e46c-9bfe-439e-ae6e-500e3c2a87e2     05/11/2021    139.51
4  557058:b25dbdb2-aa23-4706-9e50-90b2f66b60a5     05/11/2021    131.49
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Of course. How can I Add The dataframe Output?

Comment: Maybe there are rows in Users that have the correct UserID but not the correct ToDate to match with Date in the second Dataframe, but always there is a row that matches.

Comment: Done, If you see, the difference between the two first row from Users is ToDate Column... The correct Row to match is the first because the Date Field From Rate is major of the second and minor of the first row in Users

Comment: I add the Rate Column to Rate DF... If you see, the first row match with the first row of Users DF because the Date is between FromDate and Todate.
Please, note the Columns names of Rate DF.

Comment: Can contain more, same or equal but always will have an AccountID that matches with UserID

Comment: yes, the Out[5] is the rate dataframe (results dataframe)

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use outer join by both Dataframes, then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and divide column by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
Rate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Rate['Date'])
Users['FromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(Users['FromDate'])
Users['ToDate'] = pd.to_datetime(Users['ToDate'])

df = Users.merge(Rate.rename(columns={'AccountID':'UserID'}), on='UserID', how='outer')
df = df[df['Date'].between(df['FromDate'], df['ToDate'])]
df['new'] = df['BaseSalaryUSD'].div(18)
print (df)
                                        UserID  Active  BaseSalaryCOP  \
0  557058:36103848-2606-4d87-9af8-b0498f1c6713    True        9405749   
2  557058:7df66ef4-b04d-4ce9-9cdc-55751909a61e    True        3775657   
3  557058:b0a4e46c-9bfe-439e-ae6e-500e3c2a87e2    True        9542508   
4  557058:b25dbdb2-aa23-4706-9e50-90b2f66b60a5    True        8994035   

   BaseSalaryUSD   FromDate     ToDate       Date    rate         new  
0        2475.20 2020-05-11 2021-05-11 2021-04-21  137.51  137.511111  
2         993.59 2020-05-11 2021-05-11 2021-05-11   55.19   55.199444  
3        2511.19 2020-05-11 2021-05-11 2021-05-11  139.51  139.510556  
4        2366.85 2020-05-11 2021-05-11 2021-05-11  131.49  131.491667
```